# How to bind mount paths once pivot root is done

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

Background:
I am setting up a pivot root environment for my process successfully, using [minijail](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/minijail/+/HEAD/libminijail.c#694) library. This puts my process in its own mount namespace.

Problem:
Once the process is pivot-rooted, is it possible I can bind mount paths from outside into the pivot rooted environment.

eg:
After pivot root the mount info for my process is like below, where

```
/mnt is the pivot root (new root that my process sees)
/usr/lib, /usr/share and /lib are the directories I bind mounted before doing the pivot root.
```

```
sh-3.2# cat /proc/2909/mountinfo 
1751 1645 0:18 /mnt / rw,..
1752 1751 0:18 /usr/lib /usr/lib ro,relatime ...
1753 1751 0:18 /usr/share /usr/share ro,relatime ..
1754 1751 0:18 /lib /lib ro,relatime ..
```

Now I want to bind mount `/etc/xyz` (from the root namespace) at `/etc/xyz` (at process 2909 namespace) after the process is already pivot rooted.

```
sh-3.2# ls -li /proc/self/ns/mnt 
103806 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep 13 13:39 /proc/self/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
sh-3.2# ls -li /proc/2909/ns/mnt 
88440 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 app_user root 0 Sep 13 12:53 /proc/2909/ns/mnt -> mnt:[4026533175]
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: okay, thank you I posted it here now https://superuser.com/questions/1676932/how-to-bind-mount-paths-once-pivot-root-is-done